# How to convert 128 AES encryption to 256 in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to convert a 128 AES encryption to 256 in java.Previously i was using 126 and that was working fine, but i wqnt to upgrade the encryption to 256.Here is the previous code that i was using for 128

```
     private  Key generateKey() throws Exception {

     SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");

      char[] password = listOfDecodedkeys.get(1).toCharArray();
      byte[] salt = listOfDecodedkeys.get(2).getBytes(AbstractSecurity.UTF_ENCODING);
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
      byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
      return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");

  }
```

I am now using

```
       SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
```

and i have also changed the keySpec to 256

```
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 256);
```

But when i am trying to run i am getting NoSuchAlgorithmException exception. Here is the complete stacktrace

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 SecretKeyFactory not available
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.aes.security.AbstractSecurity.generateKey(AbstractSecurity.java:193)
at com.aes.security.AbstractSecurity.getCipher(AbstractSecurity.java:182)
at com.aes.security.SecurityService.encrypt(SecurityService.java:76)
at com.aes.security.SecurityService.main(SecurityService.java:165)
```

Please help i am new to encryption.

Comment: @Kayaman my code is 128 compatible , how i will convert it to 256 ? That i want to know

Comment: But why did you change the key generation algorithm?

Comment: @Kayaman if i keep the key generation algorithm same and just change the 128 to 256 then i am getting this exception  Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Sour

Comment: Note that AES with a 256-bit is no more secure than AES with a 128-bit key: Neither suffer any weakness, neither can be cracked by brute force.

Comment: @zaph but its my requirement

Answer (score 0):

The standard version of the JRE/JDK are under export restrictions. That also includes that some cryptographic algorithms are not allowed to be shipped in the standard version.

For those who are allowed to use stronger cryptography there are the [Java Cryptography Extensions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html). If you install those to your JRE/JDK you can also use e.g. AES with 256 Bit keys.

**Edit:** Better explanation why to install the JCE.

Comment: Well, by default you are not "allowed" to use strong crypography. You need to install the JCE to be able to use AES 256 at all.

Comment: ok i am adding the jar , but can you tell me what portion of my code i should change ???

Comment: None, you than are allowed to use AES 256.

Comment: not even this line ? KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 65536, 128);

Comment: Well, I thought, you would have just tested this. Change the 128 to the 256 as in your original post :-)